# WordPress theme is not being recognized because Stylesheet is missing

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My original attempt to install the theme through WordPress dashboard did not work and gave me the following error: The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet.

So I manually uploaded the unzipped files into a New Theme folder under wp-content/themes. Now I’m looking at my css files in wp-content/themes folder they are all there and match-up to the original files in the zip file which I originally downloaded.

I tried moving files up from the original sub-directory as some of the WordPress forums suggested, but "Stylesheet is missing" still shows up under Broken Themes.

Answer (score 0):

style.css should be placed at the root directory of WordPress theme. I mean,

> wp-content/themes/theme-folder

. You can place other css files to your desired location.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I downloaded my theme, and I figured it out!

You don't upload a zip file of everything you downloaded: you have to go INSIDE the main folder and find the theme folder, and zip that, then upload it. I promise, it's quick and easy! : )