# The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am beginner in WordPress and trying to  install theme in it. But I am getting

> The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the style.css
>   stylesheet.

error when I am uploading main .zip file. After getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315916/wordpress-theme-is-not-being-recognized-because-stylesheet-is-missing) solutions I am not able to get Theme folder or .zip file in main folder... my main folder directory is

[image]

Please anybody suggest me, what should I do?

Comment: put calliope and calliope-child folder in your  wp-content/themes folder and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `caliope` folder into `~wordpress_installation_folder/wp-content/themes`

If you are installing this folder it won't install as it is the whole package from theme developer, not just the theme.

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue is that it is a Plugin, not a Theme. If you are unsure, just try to install it under the Plugin section.